# When performing a join in spark, can you use join statement conditions to filter rows from shuffling?

Tags: apache-spark, join, partitioning, skew

Let's say I have the following join statement:

```
leftTable.join(
    rightTable,
    leftTable(joinColumn) =!= null and leftTable(joinColumn) === rightTable(joinColumn),
    "left_outer"
)
```

Does spark shuffle rows with a null value in the leftTable's join column or not?

I recently ran into a skew and am trying to determine if it could be because of null values. So in this case I'm wondering if spark evaluates whatever join statements it can before shuffling to minimize shuffling, or if it shuffles first and evaluates everything when matching the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the filter on the leftTable dataframe, if it doesn't affect your functionality.

```
leftTable
.where(leftTable(joinColumn) =!= null)
.join(
    rightTable,
    leftTable(joinColumn) === rightTable(joinColumn),
    "left_outer"
)
```

Comment: It does affect my functionality, we are doing a lot of enrichments on streaming data, and we can't afford to filter/drop any rows